# Writing variables into a file iterating through for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

By iterating through a nested list(list of lists) I am reading each row from the file doing some computations and writing it into a file. But I would like to write a mix of both text and variable into the output file. Just wondering how can I do it in python.

**Code:-**

```
for i in inputm[1:]:  
    #print('\n',repr(i)) 
     if '::' in i[0] or ':' not in i[0]:   
         outputfile.write('\n %s'%('This is not a valid order record.'))
```

Instead of printing 'This is not a valid record'. I would like to write a variable `i[0].split(':')[0]` and the above sentence together into the output file.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: I am not sure how to write it @TigerhawkT3

Comment: That seems to be the case in general, yes. I recommend learning some Python (with e.g. the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html)) rather than getting SO to write it for you via half a dozen questions per day.

Comment: Apply function `str()` to each of your values, and it will create a string representation suitable for passing to `write()`.

Comment: How is this different from [your question a few hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233717/writing-the-iterative-output-into-a-file-in-python)? It looks like you copy-pasted its answer into this question and are now asking for someone to write the next part.

Answer (score -1):

for python-3.x, the preferred method is via using string.format() method.

for example,

```
for i in inputm[1:]:  
#print('\n',repr(i)) 
 if '::' in i[0] or ':' not in i[0]:   
     outputfile.write('\n {}This is not a valid order record.'.format(i[0].split(':')[0]))
```

Comment: As stated in [answer], please avoid answering unclear, overly-broad, typo, opinion-based, unreproducible, or duplicate questions. Write-my-code requests and low-effort homework questions are off-topic for [so] and more suited to professional coding/tutoring services. Good questions adhere to [ask], include a [mcve], have research effort, and have the potential to be useful to future visitors. Answering inappropriate questions harms the site by making it more difficult to navigate and encouraging further such questions, which can drive away other users who volunteer their time and expertise.

Comment: @Teja - This is far from the first time I've seen you ask for code and then complain that it "doesn't work" in some vague way. You will get much better results if you actually try to gain some knowledge of Python so that you can adapt the generic code (that is intended to be helpful to future visitors, not just you) to your specific situation.

Comment: @flymousechiu It is working fine... But wondering how to print more than one variable...

Comment: read https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings about string formatting